# How can I get it work: Embedding Twitter's Web Intent

Tags: twitter, android-intent, embed

Normally Web Intent is used as a pop-up.  According to Twitter, it also provides embedding functionality.

"Some sites may **prefer to embed the unobtrusive Web Intents pop-up Javascript inline** or without a dependency to platform.twitter.com. **The snippet below** will offer the equivalent functionality without the external dependency."
 The snippet can be  found at https://gist.github.com/894540#file_intents.html
   See: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/intents

However, I can't get this snippet work.  **I copied the snippet(JavaScript) code to an html file and open that in a browser. Nothing happened!**  What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem during NYC Startup Weekend.

The snippet they provide does open up the Twitter popup, as required, but the ability of the Twitter popup window to pass a message back to your web page is a little more complicated. You will need to understand how their widgets.js code works and reproduce what's necessary to set up the RPC framework. My short-term workaround was to include a slightly modified (un-obfuscated) version of widgets.js that would not replace my button with theirs.

I will be tackling this in a week or two, if you can wait.

... or you can just include their widgets.js directly :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the vague world of the Twitter API documentation..  I think you're misunderstanding, no small part to the incredibly poor wording on the API page:
Embedding that javascript code allows you to open the twitter web intent pages in a "twitter style" popup without requiring a dependency on platform.twitter.com.  It does *not* allow you to embed a twitter intent.

You can see it at work by adding that javascript and then adding the following to your page
`<p><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?">New</a></p>`

Clicking "New" will open it in a popup.  Remove the javascript, and clicking "New" will navigate the page away to the tweet box.

It's incredibly frustrating to me they don't, at least to my knowledge, allow for proper embedding.  I know *why* they oped for this method, but it's frustrating none the less.